# Google OAuth2 authentication in page instead of popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, oauth-2.0, google-api

I'm building a Bootstrap page that requires Google authentication. I've got everything setup and working, however the popup asking for authentication bugs me.  I would rather have that in a panel.

Does anyone know if that's possible, perhaps with an iFrame or so? I can't seem to find anything.